# iOS 8 issues in showing UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a custom UIView in my application which was working correctly in iOS 7.1 but after upgrading the device to iOS 8, i start having issues with Showing it.

1) Orientation issues
2) On keyboard show issues

Screenshots from iOS 7

[image: Custome UIView on iOS 7]

[image]

How Custom UIView appear on iOS 8

[image]

Here's the code sample:

1) Calling the custom UIView

```
CustomIOS7AlertView *alertViewiOS7 = [[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] init:NULL];
[alertViewiOS7 setContainerView:[self Calculator_Create]];
[alertViewiOS7 setButtonTitles:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:languageSelectedStringForKey(dataObj.languageBundle, @"Close"), languageSelectedStringForKey(dataObj.languageBundle, @"Add"), nil]];

[alertViewiOS7 setUseMotionEffects:true];
[alertViewiOS7 show];
```

2) CustomIOS7AlertVIew class Code

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-EraWQtN1hNfmtoUXZHLXNPREdrU1QwVkdwTDNCWDhHYXk5X3hNSjdOQ3FZM3k4T0hyZUk&usp=sharing

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: You are going to have to post code and explain what you have tried so far. We aren't code psychics!

Comment: I made updates on the post and uploaded the Library Class. I hope its clear now and i hope you can help me @Tim

Comment: Have you tried the exact same code in a simulator targeting the two O/S versions?

Comment: The width & height flip-flop whenever a device is rotated in iOS 8. Make sure you're taking that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIAlertController` because `UIAlertView` has been deprecated in iOS 8.

Comment: It's actually a custom class called `CustomIOS7AlertView`. This class is subclassed from `UIView`. So OP is actually correct on that.

Comment: It would make things a lot easier if he was using `UIAlertController` though. So good call on that.

Comment: This feels like more of a comment than an answer

Comment: Didn't know why this is really happening, but i stopped using the custom alert view and used UIAlertController as @Cesare noted in his answer and it worked correctly